# Check if row has particular value in R

Tags: r, dplyr

Inside a case_when, I am currently using:

```
rowSums(select(., starts_with('type')), na.rm = TRUE) > 0
```

to check whether those rows starting with 'type' are all NA or not.

Is there a way to check if there are any '1's present in that row instead? Returns true if there is at least one 1 in that row, and false if there doesn't exist any 1s.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can change the `select` subset of data to a logical `matrix` with `==`, then apply the `rowSums` on the matrix, and check if the row wise sum is greater than 0

```
library(dplyr)
...
rowSums(select(., starts_with('type')) ==1, na.rm = TRUE) > 0
```

---

In addition to the above, it can be done using `if_any`

```
...
if_any(starts_with('type'), ~. == 1)
```